# Is it possible to proxy a stream with Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

On my cron batch I am getting images from one server and posting them to another server.

Currently I am doing this:

1. GET an image with guzzle and store in on disk inside /tmp folder
2. POST the image to another server using multipart from the /tmp folder.

I would like to know if there is any way to avoid storing the image in the /tmp folder on the server, so insetad to something like:

- GET image with guzzle as a stream and POST the stream to another server without saving it on disk.

I tried using `'stream' => true` with guzzle (https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#stream) for getting the image and posting the stream to another server, however the other server is responding with a 400.

I dont have control of the other server, but using the multipart POST with fopen('/tmp/image.png', 'r')  works.

Is there any way to accomplish proxying a stream to another server?

This is my code currently that returns 400:

```php
// Frist GET
$image = Http::withOptions([
  'stream' => true
])->get($filename);

$multipart[] = [
  'name' => $name,
  'contents' => $image
];
// Then POST
Http::withOptions([
  'query' => $query,
])
->attach($multipart)
->post(env('ENDPOINT_URL'));
```

This is previous code that works storing image to disk:

```php
// Frist GET
$image = Http::get($filename);
file_put_contents("/tmp/$filename", $image);

$multipart[] = [
  'name' => $name,
  'contents' => fopen("/tmp/$filename", 'r')
];
// Then POST
Http::withOptions([
  'query' => $query,
])
->attach($multipart)
->post(env('ENDPOINT_URL'));
```

Comment: Explain what "does not seem to work" is supposed to mean. Do you get error messages, or what are your indications for "not work"?

Comment: You can disable the option [enable_post_data_reading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading) however you will then need to manually craft the appropriate stream to forward using the `php:://input` stream

Comment: @HonkderHase sorry about that, I added some more details.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks I will check about that option